# IP-Forwarding has outgoing data but loses ingoing data after a few packages

Tags: linux, networking, debian, linux-networking, ip-forwarding

I've reached absolute rock bottom on a network configuration that I'm dealing with, so I'm hoping some of you guys might have some ideas for something I haven't thought about.

I'm struggling a lot with a network setup for a bunch of computers we have.
We are using nROK 1020 computers from Nexcom with a Sierra Wireless MC7304 modem in them.

I've set up IP forwarding in a freshly installed Debian 11, using sysctl and iptables for masquerading. I've also set up a simple dhcp server (dhcpd) working on eth0.
I'm using ModemManager in conjunction with NetworkManager to get the modem initialized and working as it should.

Here's an overview of our setup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaXfW.png

Computer A is running a DHCP server on its eth0 interface.

On Computer A itself there's absolutely no issues, I can load every site I need, no issues.
But when I plug in Computer B, get assigned an IP and try to connect, something messes up. I can ssh to a server no problem, but when I try to list a directory, I only get about half the files listed before I just stop receiving more data. After that, I can see, via WireShark, that my key-presses gets sent and I receive an ACK message, but I don't receive more than that.

Here we have a speedtest running from Computer A:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Nlx.png

And here is a speedtest running from Computer B:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5VE0.png

As we can see here, upload seems to work fine, but there's 0 download available.

Here we try to get google using wget:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymyTW.png

And this appears in wireshark at the same time:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsPTN.png

Here is the relevant sysctl configuration on Computer A:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6B4i.png

And our iptables rules:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1SMu.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGFXi.png

IP-forwarding is enabled, we can reach the internet fine. But we seem to lose data coming in.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can try?
Please feel free to comment if you need any more info and I'll do my best to provide it.

Thank you very much for reading. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, things here turned out to be an issue with the standard drivers from Debian.

The modem was using the qcserial driver and a matching net driver (which name I can't currently recall).

After downloading, building and installing a GobiSerial and GobiNet driver pair, we didn't have this problem anymore. I found the driver on Sierra Wireless own website.